# OperationalError: sub-select returns 2 columns - expected 1 in Django QuerySet

Tags: django, django-queryset

There are two models a Price model and Service model. I'm trying to find the Services that have the most prices. All of this is initially filtered by a user input query (called the entry_query). The first line (1) get the price objects that the user queries (this works). Then, line 2 (2) returns a QS with the service_code and counts of prices a service has. Then, it brings on line (3) where it gives an error (see below).

```
(1) Price_objs = Price_filter.filter(entry_query)   

(2) objs_filter=Price_objs.values_list('service__code').annotate(service_count=Count('service__code')).order_by('-service_count')

(3) serv_obj = Service.objects.filter(price__in = objs_filter).distinct()
```

Here is what line (2) outputs:

```
<QuerySet [('36430', 62), ('86003', 28), ('87149', 28), ('83516', 23), ('86317', 20), ('94640', 19), ('73502', 18), ('86658', 14), ('73721', 13), ('87070', 13), ('76942', 12), ('87081', 12), ('73560', 11), ('87798', 11), ('36415', 10), ('74177', 10), ('99211', 10), ('73100', 9), ('73221', 9), ('74176', 9), '...(remaining elements truncated)...']>
```

Here is the error that I get with line (3): 
django.db.utils.OperationalError: sub-select returns 2 columns - expected 1

Comment: I don't understand what you are doing here. Why are you annotating the service_count on the Price_objs query?

Comment: The price table has prices for services. I want to count how many prices there are for one service code - like service code '36430' has 62 prices. I want to dsiplay the Services with the most prices, so I want to order Service results by the number of prices that are available.

Comment: The other problem you have is, ordering the `Price` sub-select won't order the `Service` queryset.

You should probably start from `Service` and annotate `price__...` as related lookups.
`Service.objects.filter(price__...entry_query...).annotate(price_count=Count('price_set').order_by('-price_count')`

Or something similar to this.

Comment: This is the answer that I was looking for thanks. It worked.